# Quisiera saber como hago para pasar de un frame a otro, ejecutando el main del otro frame?

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

Quisiera saber como hago para pasar de un Jframe a otro, ejecutando el main del otro Jframe?

tengo un input en el jframe que quiero abrir desde el Jframe inicio, abro de la siguiente manera el Jframe

```
Jframe2  abrir =new Jframe2();
abrir.setVisible(true);
```

Pero de esta manera no se me ejecuta el main de ese frame2,y quisiera que se mejecute pues tengo codigo para mostrar.

Comment: Es un poco confusa tu pregunta, pero si tienes bien el código, bastaría con hacer una inicialización de la Clase del respectivo JFrame.
Lo suyo es hacer un método para inicializar la `GUI` y en su respectivo constructor llamar a este método.

Answer (score 0):

#### Creamos nuestra primera clase:

```
public class PrimeraVentanaSwing {
    //Constructor
    PrimeraVentanaSwing(){
        muestraGUI();
    }

    private void muestraGUI(){
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame marco = new JFrame("Hola mundo Swing");
        marco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        marco.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,350));
        marco.setLocation(600, 500);
        marco.setVisible(true);
        marco.pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

}
```

#### Ahora creamos nuestra segunda clase donde llamamos a ambas ventanas en el main

```
public class SegundaVentanaSwing {
    //Constructor
    SegundaVentanaSwing(){
        muestraGUI();
    }

    private void muestraGUI(){
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame marco = new JFrame("Hola mundo Swing");
        marco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        marco.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,350));
        marco.setLocation(650, 550);
        marco.setVisible(true);
        marco.pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->{
            PrimeraVentanaSwing pVS = new PrimeraVentanaSwing();
            SegundaVentanaSwing pVS2 = new SegundaVentanaSwing();
        });
    }

}
```

### Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]